# Is akka persist callback param just the same intance as persisted event

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

```
def persist[A](event: A)(handler: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit

def persistAll[A](events: Seq[A])(handler: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

For above method, is param passed to `handler` guaranted to be exactly the same(with same identifyHashCode) instance as the persisted `event` ?

According to my few tests, they are actually same, but I don't know akka will always ensure this even in the future release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code, we can see they are exactly the same.

```
def persist[A](event: A)(handler: A => Unit): Unit = {
  if (recoveryRunning) throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot persist during replay. Events can be persisted when receiving RecoveryCompleted or later.")
  pendingStashingPersistInvocations += 1
  pendingInvocations addLast StashingHandlerInvocation(event, handler.asInstanceOf[Any => Unit])
  eventBatch ::= AtomicWrite(PersistentRepr(event, persistenceId = persistenceId,
    sequenceNr = nextSequenceNr(), writerUuid = writerUuid, sender = sender()))
}
```

You can see the same `event` be passed to `AtomicWrite` for persist & also passed to `StashingHandlerInvocation` for handle. I didn't see any reason for akka team to change this later. But no one can promise for future release even the maintainer I think, maybe you need to wait the man from lightbend. FYI.

Comment: This official maillist may help you: [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/akka-user)